# Django Error in using jinja code inside style tag

Tags: python, html, css, django, jinja2

An error is generated while using jinja code inside HTML style tag
I think it's because of the style tag. But it,s perfectly fine to use jinja code inside a style tag. so can't understand what is the problem here. am I missing something ?

error statement

```
 at-rule or selector expectedcss(css-ruleorselectorexpected)
```

code

```
   <style>
     {% block css %} {% endblock %}
     </style>
```

Comment: Maybe `css` is a reserved word?  Try naming it something else.

Comment: @JohnGordon no it's not working, I think it's because of the style tag. But it's perfectly fine to use jinja code inside a style tag. so can't understand what is the problem here

Comment: Double check if you have added ``` {% load static %} ```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative way of this is, for example:

Inside Template HTML File:

```
{% block css %} {% endblock css %}
```

Inside Index HTML File:

```
{% block css %} <style> </style> {% endblock css %}
```

This works fine for me and that error is also not seen. Thanks